# how containsall method from collections interface works in java?

Tags: java

if I have two lists of objects from Collection interface

list 1 = {John, Tim, Tom}

list 2 = {John, Tim}

and both of the lists are instances of ArrayList

how does Java knows if list2 is contained in list1 with list1.containsall(list2)?
I knows that Java uses contain method inside the implementation of containsall() method, and the contain method uses the equal() method.  I understand the differences but I am not sure how Java iterates through the elements of list 1.

so If I use list1.containsAll(list2),, constainsAll() method is implemented with a loop that iterates through every object of in this case, list2, and throws false if one of the elements is not in list 1.

So my main question is how does JAVA know that list 1 contains all of the elements without another loop to iterate through the elements of list 1?  Does java does the work internally or something?

I currently know that to do such a thing, I would have to use

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(), i++)

list1.get(i).constainsAll(list2);

,,
that seems more logical to me taking into consideration that I would have to modified the code for containsAll to work correctly and also implement the method of get()

Comment: See the implementation of [`AbstractCollection#containsAll`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/c5d02f908fb2/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l316). What do you mean by "how does java know that list 1 contains all of the elements without another loop"? One loop is enough to check, because the "2nd loop" is done by the `contains` method when it is called for each element being checked.

Comment: so how does list 1 jumps to its next element if it doesnt have a loop to iterate? list 2 will have its 2nd loop implemented in the method, but how does list 1 iterates through its elements without a loop?

Comment: int [] list 1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4] ; int [] list 2 = [1,2,3]  ,,,, to check if the elements of list 2 are in list 1, two loops are required, with time complexity of (list1.length * list2.length

Comment: why is it different for lists?

Comment: Yes. If you check the link I provided, you can see that it does exactly that, just implicitly. [`containsAll`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/c5d02f908fb2/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l316) provides a loop for "List 2", as this loops the list that is provided as the method parameter. Inside that loop, [`contains`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/c5d02f908fb2/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l98) is called on "List 1" with the current object from the other loop as the method parameter, where the second loop runs.

Comment: thank you for the link, very informative!.  one last question, does the object created inside the method of contain, Iterator <E> it = iterator (),  point or references to list 1?

Comment: Yes, this will create an iterator for the specified collection, in this case the collection where the initial method was called on (List 1). See [java.util.Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). This is basically "the second loop".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to answer this formally because I think it is a good Question.

The `containsAll` method iterates through the provided collection and performs the `contains()` method on each entry which also iterates through the other list being compared. See below extract from [java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/c5d02f908fb2/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l316) code

```java
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (!contains(e))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

and

```java
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (o==null) {
            while (it.hasNext())
                if (it.next()==null)
                    return true;
        } else {
            while (it.hasNext())
                if (o.equals(it.next()))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This makes this o(n^2) (Worst case scenario if the last values do not match or if the list actually matches) (Which is really bad, especially if you have big collections which you are comparing).

a better approach would be to do something like the following: (Obviously this needs to be adjusted if you are using objects or other collections apart from strings and do some null checks or something)

```java
 public boolean containsAllStrings(List<String> list1, List<String> List2) {
        Map<String, String> list1Map = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> c));
        return List2.stream().allMatch(list1Map::containsKey);
    }
```

This way it Iterates a max number of 2n (one for adding items to map and one for comparing) times (n being the biggest list of the 2) and not n^2.

It may seem the same but hash maps are nice because they contain a pointer to the value in memory (Using the hashed value of the key) and do not iterate overall all the values, making accessing a value in a map always o(1). Which is optimal.

Obviously, there are tradeoffs between approaches like memory utilization, but for speed, this is the best approach.